# Some coding tags are visible in Drupal page

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-6

```
Title:
field_blog_posterimg:
field_blog_poster:
field_blog_posterposition:
```

How to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

```
unset($node->field_blog_posterimg);
```

Put this in your node template and repeat for each field

Alternatively you can remove those fields from the admin/structure page if you don't need them

Comment: i am new to it.. Please can you guide me step wise?

Comment: This is Drupal 7 correct? If you click "Structure" then "Content Types", you should see a list of content types. You need to select the content type of the page (looks like blog) and then press "Edit". You will then be able to remove the fields blog_posterimg, blog_poster and blog_posterposition which will prevent them from appearing on the rendered page.

Comment: http://www.synergyplus.uk.com/synergyplus-news
Here is the webpage.. can you please see it?

Comment: I can see the page but can't help without being able to login to the CMS or access the files.

Comment: I can however see that the site is running Drupal 7, you should be able to login to the admin area and follow the steps in comment #2 above

Comment: http://www.synergyplus.uk.com/business-telephony-systems also you can see here on side bar

Comment: Are you using separate templates for each node type?